# Why returning an ofstream does not give error in Dev-C++, but it does in Visual C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, type-conversion

I wrote a code using Dev-C++ for Windows that compiled and worked perfectly. The code included the following function:

```
bool Output::OpenTrace(std::vector<Species> &sp, ofstream &trace)
{
    trace.open("trace.txt");
    if(!trace)
    {
        cerr << "Impossible to open trace file\n";  
        return 1;
    }
    
    trace << "TIME";
    for(int npart = 0; npart < sp[1]._number; npart++)
    {
        trace << "\t PART" << npart+1 << "\t";
    }trace << std::endl;
    
    return trace;
}
```

This code, when called from main worked perfectly when the compilation happened in Dev-C++. However, moving to Visual C++, the compilation gives me the error

> E0413 cannot transform std::ofstream to bool

However, if in Visual C++ I change `return trace` by `return trace.good()`, then it works as expected. Why was not necessary to write `trace.good()` in Dev-C++, but it is in Visual C++?

Comment: The conversion has changed over time and is `explicit` since C++11 see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool  live - https://godbolt.org/z/9fzMEb7Gr - swap the 2 lines

Comment: Note that `return 1; is equivalent to `return true;`. That does't seem like the right return value when the function can't open the trace file.

Comment: I had return -1 but been told that thas was stupid. Should I use `return 0` instead?

Comment: @AliEsquembreKucukalic return either `true` or `false` as you have declared the return type `bool`. `false` would seem best for the error case.

Comment: `return trace.operator bool();` or `return trace.good();` or even `return !!trace;` or `return static_cast<bool>(trace);` all of which means OpenTrace returns `true` (via `return 1;`) if it **fails** to open the file, or returns `true` if it opens the file and the ofstream object is in a good state.  That may be a confusing return semantic for the caller.

Comment: Probably the reason for the differences between `Dev-C++` and `Visual C++` will be which C++ Standard each is targeting.  `Dev-C++` is probably targeting a version of the standard before C++11 and `Visual C++` is targeting C++11 or greater.  As a note you should always check which version of the C++ Standard your tool-chain is targeting and set it to what you need as appropriate.

Comment: @RichardCritten Actually, that is what I was thinking, but I found it weird since I am using C++11 in Dev-C++, and I thought it was the default in Visual. It seems it is not. Thank you!